# how to send a NSDate to another view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, calendar, ios5

How do I send a `NSDate` object to another view?

Trying to get the selected date form a calendar ([Si-Calendar](https://github.com/voidparadox/Si-Calendar/)) and use it into another view...

Comment: Please me more clear in your question. I think @beryllium gave the answer you're looking for but try to specify what you mean more precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the README file on GitHub, changes in the selected date will be sent to the object you set as delegate for the CalendarViewController object. The method that will be called is:

```
- (void)calendarViewController:(CalendarViewController *)aCalendarViewController dateDidChange:(NSDate *)aDate
```

If you then want to pass that date on to a new viewController, make sure it has an `NSDate` property, let's say it goes by the name *date*. You can then pass the date to the other viewController (let's say it's called *otherViewController*) this way:

```
otherViewController.date = aDate;
```

This is a normal way of passing objects through viewControllers, you'd do it like this for any type of object. The basic idiom is:

1. Have a property of the type of object you want to pass in the viewController you want to pass it to
2. Set the property. If it was defined with the `retain` or `strong` keyword, it'll be retained.

That's all!
Hope this helps

Comment: Where do I place `otherViewController.date = aDate;`?

Comment: You place that in the viewController from where you want to pass the date to the otherViewController.

Comment: I'm getting: Property 'date' not found on object of type 'OtherViewController' (I know that I have to import OtherViewController.h)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to populate that `NSDate` to `titleForHeaderInSection` method ? (I want to display it; don't know how to get it...)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a property in another view. Then `anoterView.date = myDate;`
2. Use global variable which accessible in both views ().