# passing data to secondViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios5, pushviewcontroller, addsubview

Trying to send some data form my previous ViewController. To be more clear trying to send the selected date of the [Si-Calendar](https://github.com/voidparadox/Si-Calendar) to my secondView.

I'm adding the Calendar to my view in this way:

```
CalendarMonth *aCalendarView = [[CalendarMonth alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 324) logic:calendarLogic];
[aCalendarView selectButtonForDate:selectedDate];
[self.view addSubview:aCalendarView];
```

How do I use selected date and send it to my secondViewController (a UIView in which I'll display the selected date)?

Comment: Sending an object to a view or a controller is syntactical the same. objective-c doesn't know the difference between a view and a controller. this is not an language feature but a pattern. for obj-c it is just passing an object from one object to another. so your question got answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243266/how-to-send-a-nsdate-to-another-view

Comment: Could you explain the math behind this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a date property to your secondViewController, and set it appropriately when you create the instance...

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what the first or second viewController is, but in general you could use a delegate for this purpose. For an example on how to do this, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to exchange data between view controllers, just take them as objects.

1. first controller hold a ref of the second controller, and transfer data using variables and methods
2. use delegate,
3. use notification

etc.

Answer (score 1):

i can see that you are adding the CalenderMonth as the subview to another view. So if you dont release it (until u create the second view controller), you can set the selectedDate of the calender month obj to an iVar of second view controller. Else Create a delegate for CalenderMonth class. Set the second view controller as the delegate of the CalenderMonth and do the necessary.